# Turn 3D rotation of vector object into vector object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-manipulation

I have a vector object in Illustrator CS3. For the sake of simplicity, let's say it's a rectangle. It has been "3D-rotated", and now appears to me to be a slightly skewed parallelogram. Of course, this 3d effect could be discarded at any time and it would appear to me again in its true shape, a rectangle.

What I want is for my vector object to be the slightly skewed parallelogram. I want to be able to manipulate that parallelogram directly as a vector object. As if that had been my original shape. Does that make sense?

Thank you! Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the 3D effect but mentain the appearance just do
**Object > Expand Appearance**.